# SQL syntax, nodejs sequalize, multiple lines at once

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im trying to populate mysql db with the dummy data at the start up but i keep getting this werid problem

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Teachers
```

I tried to check around if that syntax is right and most of the online checkers tell me that there is nothing wrong with that. But despite that, it gives me this error. However if i try to query the database through mysql workbench it works fine and inserts data without any problems.

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const config = require('./config')

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: config.db.options.host,
  user: config.db.user,
  password: config.db.password
})
let superScript = `
  USE school;
 INSERT INTO Teachers
    (FirstName,LastName,Gender,Address,PhoneNumber,Email ,Facebook_ID                 
   ,Qualification, Good_at,Personal_Description,Teachering_Experience,Music_skill,Language_skill,Image_URL) 
  VALUES("Glennys","Looker","Male","125 Melbourne street", 
  "1234567890","abc123@gmail.com"
    ,"GlennysFB","Master","Piano"
    ,"I am a pianist and composer who has taught people of all ages   and levels, including absolute beginners, adult students, and taking     students through AMEB or VCE exams. "
    ," 7 Years Teaching Experience","Piano","English,Japanese"
    ,"https://segundadivisionweb.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/profesor-    de-musica.jpg");`;


 function createDB () {
  con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err
console.log('Connected!')
con.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${config.db.database}`, 
 function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Database created')
})
con.query(superScript, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
    });




  })
}
```

What should i do to insert that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody had the same problem, here is the solution

```
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.db.options.host,
    user: config.db.user,
    password: config.db.password,
    database: config.db.database,
    multipleStatements: true
  })
```

This will allow u to insert as many elements as u like in 1 string

Answer (score 0):

Not a programmer, but AFAIK you can't issue multiple statements in one.

Try it like this (without the USE statement):

```
let superScript = `
 INSERT INTO school.Teachers
```

or put the DB into your connection settings.